# Has Facebook removed CSharp SDK?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api

I've had a working program that used Facebook's **CSharp** SDK to capture some public data from my Facebook members.. However, since the **12th of April** *(Facebook's v2.6 Update)* my program stopped working. I've also noticed that Facebook's **CSharp** SDK cant be found anymore at *https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks*

I'm not sure what's going on, or if this is part of a normal procedure. So please, if anyone has any insights, please feel free to share!

Comment: afaik the c# sdk was never official, and if you´re talking about that one: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk - it has not been updated since more than a year as it seems. you should consider switching (js, node.js, php, ...)

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook C# SDK (which is actually unofficial) still works in Windows 8.1. It stopped working in Windows 10, though, because of conflicts with the HTTP/2 protocol.

A temporary workaround is going to Internet Explorer > Internet Options > Advanced > **Uncheck HTTP 1.1 and HTTP 1.1 through proxy**